# When connected to work VPN I can't access my local VMs

Tags: virtual-machine, vpn

Simple question, hope there is a simple solution.
When I connect to work VPN, I can't access my local VMs through SSH or borwser. If I ping the VMs I get timed out.
Is there any way to make it work together?

Comment: Please show the routing table (route -n) before and after VPN is on. Most probably the same address network is used or the VPN inserts some routing entries that inhibit the connection to the VM.

Comment: yes, the same address is used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the same address is used for both the work VPN and local VMs then you have two opportunities:

1) (best) reconfigure the local VMs addresses in another non public class (ie. if you have 192.168.1.X put 192.168.2.x and so on) so the two address spaces will not collide

2) (more difficult) put a few static routes that point directly to your VM addresses (or alternatively to the VPN) on the specific interface (so for example forcing an IP like 192.168.1.44 to eth0).

Be aware that the second solution is also depending on the type of network you created in the VM (bridged, NAT and so on) so most probably the first solution is the far easiest one.

Comment: Could you give more details about how to do this?